# block mouseout event listener if onclick is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was trying 3 different action of mouse (mouseout, mouseenter and onclick) in which if user click on a image then the mouseout event should be blocked.

```
<div class="side-thumbnail">
 <img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-bw.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-bw.png'" alt="face" class="small-faceHit" data-id="firstpeople"> <br>
 <img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/08Georg-Front.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/08Georg-Front-Active.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/08Georg-Front.png'" alt="face" class="small-faceHit" data-id="secondpeople"> <br>
.................
</div>
```

you can see the full code in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/gam54vuf/4/)

Comment: Do you want to make user unable to leave the picture area with their cursor as they are **pressing** mouse on it?

Comment: No I just want the hover and click effect over image and also mouse out if it is not clicked and users should be able to leave the picture area too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean CSS based solution using CSS Filters.

https://jsfiddle.net/f1b3ugo5/

CSS:

```
img{width:150px;}

img.active, img.inactive:hover {
  filter:none;
-webkit-filter: none;
-moz-filter: none;
-ie-filter: none;
-o-filter: none;
}
img.inactive {
filter:url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version=\"1.1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"><filter id=\"grayscale\"><feColorMatrix type=\"matrix\" values=\"0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\"/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
filter: gray;
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ie-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);

}
```

JS:

```
'use strict';

var add_events = function( img, opts ){
  this.image = img;
  this.setup_listener();
  return this;
}
add_events.prototype.activate = function(){
    this.image.classList.remove('inactive');
    this.image.classList.add('active');
};
add_events.prototype.deactivate = function(){
    this.image.is_active = false;
    this.image.classList.remove('active');
    this.image.classList.add('inactive');
};
add_events.prototype.setup_listener = function(){
  var _this = this;
  this.image.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    add_events.deactivate_all( _this );
    if( this.is_active ){ 
    _this.deactivate();
    }
    else{ 
    this.is_active = true;
    _this.activate();
    }
  },false);
};

add_events.deactivate_all = function( current ){
  for( var i = 0; i < holder.length; ++i ){
    if(holder[i]===current){}
    else{ holder[i].deactivate(); }
  }
};

var holder = [], images = document.querySelectorAll( '.small-faceHit' );
for( var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i ){
  holder.push(new add_events( images[i], {}) );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="side-thumbnail">

<img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit inactive" id="toggle-image" data-id="firstpeople">

<img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit inactive" id="toggle-image" data-id="firstpeople">

<img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit inactive" id="toggle-image" data-id="firstpeople">

<img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit inactive" id="toggle-image" data-id="firstpeople">

</div>
```

Comment: Don't you think this is too much javascript for this small thing ?

Comment: Yes... Well. It could be handled more lightweight. But this way it is without JQuery and gives an extra of control.

Comment: man I tried in fiddle and your code work like a champ but when I put in my site it needs double click to remove grayscale, but i copied the source from my site and put again in fiddle again your code works as a champ, I don't know what is causing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this without using two images for each item but it would require a little javascript.

Here basically, you are loading the colored images only and applying CSS filters to make the image look greyscale

```js
$(document).on('click', '.greyscale', function(){
    $('.side-thumbnail img').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('greyscale'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('greyscale');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
    });
    $(this).removeClass('greyscale');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
img{width:150px;}

.greyscale{
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
    -webkit-transition: all .6s ease; /* Fade to color for Chrome and Safari */
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Fix for transition flickering */
}


.greyscale:hover, .selected{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="side-thumbnail">

    <img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/andreas-front-active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit greyscale" data-id="firstpeople"> <br>
   
    <img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/08Georg-Front-Active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit greyscale" data-id="secondpeople"> <br>

    <img src="http://dev.kis-com.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/02-Naomi-Front-Active.png" alt="face" class="small-faceHit greyscale" data-id="thirdpeople">

</div>
```

Comment: on clicking second image there's a color image which was clicked before but it should be grayscale

Comment: from your code i have achieve up to this by adding two lines
`$('.small-faceHit').removeClass('selected');`
     `$('.small-faceHit').addClass('greyscale');`
https://jsfiddle.net/sus_hill/f1b3ugo5/10/

Comment: It is behaving right in fiddle but when i use It in site it works only in double click. I don't know why but may be another onclick function to the same thing
you can view the full code in http://codepen.io/sus_hill/pen/QGwZaW

Comment: can you share the exact code you have on your site ?